# How to perform absolute useRouter in Next.js 14?

Tags: next.js, routes

I use router = useRouter(). Then router.push('auth/new-password') from path 'auth/login/approve'. And in fact i get routing to 'auth/login/auth/new-password'. What is logic about that?
How to make redirect to 'auth/new-password' from 'auth/login/approve'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to redirect to the `auth/new-password` you can do something like this

```js
'use client'
 
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'
 
export default function Page() {
  const router = useRouter()
 
  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={() => router.push('/auth/new-password')}>
      Dashboard
    </button>
  )
```

make sure to add forward slash before the "auth". You can also use `redirect` from the `next/navigation` package to redirect user